# Alternatives to Google Book Search API?

Tags: api, google-books

I'm looking for alternatives to Google Book Search API.

Ideally, something with more detailed information about books.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the RESTful API from ISBN DB http://isbndb.com/api/v2/docs

Answer (score 2):

I have been using the API from the literature social network GoodReads   https://www.goodreads.com/api

I find the results are a lot more relevant then Google Books because there relevance ordering takes a books popularity on the site into account. You don't get results like multiple versions of the same book or some obscure essay (this could be a plus or a minus depending on what you're doing).

However, the images are often missing and when they are there they are very low res!

Comment: Unfortunately, the API was discontinued in SDC 2020 and no alternative has been offered yet, as of May 2021.
https://www.goodreads.com/api